# Modificar variable y refrescar pagina web con nuevo valor conservando valor de otras variables

Tags: php, html

Mi problema es el siguiente: he creado una pagina web en la que una de sus variables es un contador que se incrementa y decrementa al pulsar botones mas/menos, al hacerlo quiero que refresque la pagina conservando el valor de las demas variables que gestiona la pagina pero conservando el nuevo valor de la variables contador..

He usado las diversas etiquetas input dentro de un Form (aunque realmente no se envia ningun formulario ) con metodo POST y GET pero refresca la pagina y no conserva los valores que tienen en ese momento las variables.

Le muestro el codigo simplificado de mi pagina (MiWeb.php) a ver si me pueden ayudar gracias.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<?php

          $a        = $_GET['a'];
          $b        = $_GET['b']; 
          $c        = $_GET['c'];
          $d        = $_GET['d'];
          $e        = $_GET['e'];
          $Contador = $_GET['Cont'];      

        .....................
          .....................
          .....................


  function UnoMas()
   {
     $Contador ++;   
   }

?>

</head>

<body>
    
 <?php  

  //BOTON MAS (deberia : incrementa en uno $Contador, refresca pagina sin variar 
  //los valores de las demas variables)

  echo '<td width ="33%" >';
 
  echo '<form method="get" >  
      
        echo '<a href="MiWeb.php?a=$a&b=$b&c=$c&d=$d&e=$e&Cont=$Contador">';

          echo '<button  onclick="UnoMas();"><img src="mas.png"></button>';
  
      echo '</a>';

    echo '</form>'

  echo '</td>';

?>

</body>
```

Comment: Con Javascript, puedes guardar los valores de las variables en localStorage https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Puedes guardar datos nuevos en otro formulario, y consultarlos al refrescar la pagina

```js
$nombre="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['nombre'])){
$nombre=$_REQUEST['nombre'];
}
 
$apellido="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['apellido'])){
$apellido=$_REQUEST['apellido'];
}
 
$carrera="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['carrera'])){
$carrera=$_REQUEST['carrera'];
}
 
$materia="";
if (!empty($_REQUEST['materia'])){
$materia=$_REQUEST['materia'];
}
 
//Luego sobrescribo el txt
 
$archivo="datos.txt";
 
     $file=fopen($archivo,"a");
     fwrite($file,$nombre.$apellido.$carrera.$materia);
     fclose($file);
```

Con esto guardas datos nuevos, luego solo tienes que leerlos en tu Pagina

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/301370)

Comment: Editada la respuesta